# QGIS print composer: can I select features whose attributes to show?

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I am using the atlas to generate a number of maps.  Each map is of a particular zone represented by a multiline vector layer.  I have another layer with point data and each map has an attribute table with the point data.  It seems that I have just two choices:

1. I can have all the points in the table
2. or I can have just those points that are visible on the map

I want a third possibility:  just those points associated with the zone. i.e. an option to filter points relative to the 'current' feature -- something like "zone" = atlas.zone_name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible in the current development version of QGIS (which will eventually become 2.6 - there's instructions on how to obtain development snapshots [here](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html)), and a potential workaround is available in 2.4.

Both methods are done by checking the "Filter with" checkbox under the table's "item properties" tab, and entering a filter expression.

**In development snapshots:**

Assuming your point layer has a column called "zone", and the zone table has a column "zone_name", you would set the attribute table's filter to something like:

```
"zone" = attribute(  $atlasfeature ,'zone_name')
```

**In QGIS 2.4**

While you can't do a filter using attributes from the atlas layer, you can use a geographic filter from the table with the atlas. This may or may not work for your particular use case. The expression would be something like this:

```
intersects(  buffer ( $geometry , 10), $atlasgeometry )
```

This would show points within 10 map units of your atlas multiline layer.

Comment: This works, sort of.  The real issue is that I need different tolerances for each map.  Still it is much better than nothing.  I suspect that the real problem is that the features are messy collection of lines rather than nice polygons.  I probably should define another polygon layer which explicitly marks the boundary and use that as an invisible feature.

Comment: I have generated a set of polygons the actually fully enclose the areas and it now works well.  When 2.6 comes out I will move to doing it using data based filters.

Comment: Great to hear! The data based filters in 2.6 will also be much faster than the geography based ones possible in 2.4.